# How to install my own Java library?

Tags: android

I created a Java class for helping me to use some common debuggin stuffs, for example to get the type of value, I have a method call typeOf()

```
Help help = new Help();
String s = "Something";
help.alert(help.typeOf(s));
```

above is a sample code in my class

Now every time I start a project, I need copy the class file to my project, so I want to know is there any way I can install this in my OS, then can import it to any of project whenever I needed.

In `C` you can move the header file to a location, then you can `#include` it whenever you want

Comment: create a library project and import it in your app. p.s. i wont recommend this approach for tasks like typeOf(), when you can directly use `instanceOf` wherever necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I can't use `instanceOf` on a premitive type, and my Help class has tones of other helping stuff.

I didn't get that, how can I make a library project. Because I never heard about, can u explain me please.

Comment: I am not sure why you cant use instance of with primitive objects. As I have used instancenof String imstanceOf Integer instanceOf Double etc too. and when it comes to library project. i guess you can just google it. there are many answers related to library projects on stack overflow

Comment: Have you checked the youtube video? Basically what you need to do is to export your Help Class as a jar file
file—>export—>java—>JAR File
Then add the jar file as external library to the project in which you want to use it.

Comment: `int a = 12` you can't use `instanceOf` on this variable, and it's fine if there is another way to do it, I want to to know is there any way I can install that jar file to the library, like in `C` you can move your header file to a location, and you include it whenever you want without moving that file everytime you create a project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you using gradle, you can learn it from [Building your own Android library](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Building-your-own-Android-library) but need to publish your library to  jCenter or Maven Central.

Fortunately, you can make the library as a local artifact using `maven plugin` in the library. Read more at [Deploying an Artifact to the Local Cache in Gradle](https://dzone.com/articles/deploying-artifact-local-cache)

In your project, you need to add mavenLocal() to the repositories in your root build.gradle:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  mavenLocal()
}
```

And add the dependencies to your project build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.your.library:x.y.z'
  ...
}
```

But if your project is shared in your local network, you need to use Repository management like [Artifactory by JFrog](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/) or [Nexus Repository Manager by Sonatype](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/).

Comment: good answer. also, if you are hosting your library on github you can access it through jitpack by adding `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` to your `repositories` (@see https://jitpack.io).

Comment: Thanks guys, this is what I was looking for :)

Comment: @trooper: I've never try using github as a direct repository for my library. So, this is a new thing for me, so I don't have a credibility about it. But you're the one. Would you like to edit the answer to add about it?

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך I'm not sure there is much to add (its relatively new to me as well). My experience with it has been forking an existing library, making my own changes, and then referencing the fork through jitpack. Its all very automatic (no extra steps required to publish, etc).

Comment: Still, I've no experience with it whatsoever. I'll try to learn it. Thank you very much for the info. :)